# Remove content-length header from wp_remote_post

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script, post

I am having big issues doing a POST request from wordpress backend.
This is the request I try to make. The AppsSCript is a doPost() endpoint echo-ing the request. It gives me a 400 error.

```
$body = array(
    'firstName' => 'WhyWontYouWork'
);

$args = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        //'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
         ),
        'body' => $body
    );

    $request = wp_remote_post ($url, $args);
    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
```

I found out with insomnia, that having a content-length header in the POST request is making Apps Script go crazy. If I remove it, all works.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps,

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api/endpoint';
$args = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'timeout' => 30,
  'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  ),
  'body' => json_encode( array( 'data' => 'value' ) ),
);

// Remove the Content-Length header
unset( $args['headers']['Content-Length'] );
// Or Change it
$args['headers']['Content-Length'] = 20166 // in decimal bytes


// Make the remote post request
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );

// Check for errors
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
  // Handle error
} else {
  // Handle success
}
```

Comment: This works! 
Great! Strange I have to omit the Content-Length header here.